# Jooq count method getting wrapped in backticks

Tags: java, mysql, jooq

I recently updated a project's jooq version from 3.13.5 to 3.14.15.  I've rerun jooq-codegen.  I'm using MySQL 5.7.

When running one of my tests - it performs a `DAOImpl.exists`.  That call generates the following exception:

```
org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [select `count`(*) from `users` where `users`.`id` = ?]; You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*) from `users` where `users`.`id` = 1094' at line 1

    at org.jooq_3.14.15.MYSQL.debug(Unknown Source)
    at org.jooq.impl.Tools.translate(Tools.java:2903)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultExecuteContext.sqlException(DefaultExecuteContext.java:757)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:389)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.fetchLazy(AbstractResultQuery.java:453)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.fetchLazy(AbstractResultQuery.java:422)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.fetchLazyNonAutoClosing(AbstractResultQuery.java:436)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.fetchOne(AbstractResultQuery.java:613)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.fetchOne(AbstractResultQuery.java:565)
    at org.jooq.impl.SelectImpl.fetchOne(SelectImpl.java:3034)
    at org.jooq.impl.DAOImpl.existsById(DAOImpl.java:300)
    at org.jooq.impl.DAOImpl.exists(DAOImpl.java:288)
```

The problem is that `count` has backticks.  It should be `` select count(*) from `users` where `users`.`id` = ? ``

Has anyone run into this before and know how to fix it?  TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably specified `RenderQuotedNames.ALWAYS` and ran into this problem? https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/9931

The setting `ALWAYS` is misleading. It really means literally always, though people probably read it as `ALWAYSISH_I_E_ONLY_WHEN_IT_MAKES_SENSE`. Probably a naming design error, but what you want is `EXPLICIT_DEFAULT_QUOTED`, see the documentation:
https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/custom-settings/settings-name-style/

#### RenderQuotedNames

- `ALWAYS`: This will quote all identifiers.
- `EXPLICIT_DEFAULT_QUOTED`: This will quote all identifiers, which are not explicitly unquoted using [`DSL.unquotedName()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#unquotedName(String)).
- `EXPLICIT_DEFAULT_UNQUOTED`: This will not quote any identifiers, unless they are explicitly quoted using [`DSL.quotedName()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#quotedName(String)).
- `NEVER`: This will not quote any identifiers.

`COUNT` in `DSL.count()`is an explicitly unquoted name, and `ALWAYS` will override that.